# Bonus for my friend

Tags: bitcoin-core, value

I have used original bitcoin client for first time. When I opened it showed the account balance is 1,000.0. Why is this bonus of 1 btc?

Now my friend tried opening client but his account balance is 0. How he can apply bonus?

How much is my balance in €?

Comment: There is no bonus, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bonus. There's no way to know what exactly happened to you without sharing screenshots and the relevant Bitcoin address.